# Creating an ifelse statement that is conditional by factor level

Tags: r

I'm new to R, so I'm sorry if this is obvious. But, I've been stuck on this for a while, but can have been fruitless in finding answers thus far.

Data frame:

```
1  b c id e
2  0 1 45 5
3  1 0 45 7
4  0 1 48 5
5  1 0 46 7
```

Desired result:

```
1 b c id e f
2 0 1 45 5 1
3 1 0 45 7 1
4 0 1 48 5 0
5 1 0 46 7 0
```

What I'm trying to do: I am trying to create column F based on levels of b and c for people with the same ID. Column E is still important to me along with other omitted values, so I can't collapse the data on ID.

The closest I've gotten:

```
    library(dplyr)
    df2 <- df %>% 
     group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(ifelse(b == 1 & c == 1, 1, 0))
```

But, I think my problem there is that I'm not using `dplyr::group_by` correctly so I'm essentially doing a base `ifelse` statement.

Comment: What about b and c makes f = 1 for id ==45 and 0 for the other two?

Comment: Because it has a 1 across both columns for the subject. But, the subjects who only occur once only have an observation for b or c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need an `ifelse` here

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(f = as.integer(any(b) &  any(c)))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups: id [3]
#      b     c    id     e     f
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     0     1    45     5     1
#2     1     0    45     7     1
#3     0     1    48     5     0
#4     1     0    46     7     0
```